# How to save an ICollection<int> with EF CTP5

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have this properties for my class: Team

```
[Key]
public virtual long Id { get; set; }

public Guid ClubIdentifier { get; set; }
public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }
public TeamAgeCategoryEnum TeamAgeCategory { get; set; }
public ICollection<int> BirthYears { get; set; }
```

How can I save the content in property BirthYears to my database, I am letting the EF create my database based on the model, but the property BirthYears is left out in my database. I would have expected a new table that hold the int-value and my Team Id value.

What have I missed, I guess I need to do something OnModelCreating method in my repository class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType>` class you will see the following signature for defining a one-to-many relationship (which is your relation between `Team` and `BirthYears`):

```
HasMany<TTargetEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, ICollection<TTargetEntity>>>
   navigationPropertyExpression) where TTargetEntity : class;
```

As you can see, there is a constraint `where TTargetEntity : class` which requires that `BirthYears` is a collection of `class` objects. `int` isn't a class, so the mapping won't be possible.

The only workaround I can see is to define a little class ...

```
public class BirthYear
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

... and then use this in your collection in the class Team:

```
public ICollection<BirthYear> BirthYears { get; set; }
```

The mapping conventions should automatically create a one-to-many relationship, so that you don't need the Fluent API to set up the association.

**Edit**

Correction according to Ladislav's correct critic in the comments:

The class `BirthYear` needs an additional Key property. I've added a property `Id`.

Also I guess that `BirthYears` will be a property dependent on `Team`. The mapping conventions will create an optional relationship from `BirthYear` to `Team`. I think it would be more suited for the model to make this relationship required by using the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasMany(t => t.BirthYears)
            .WithRequired();
```

This will automatically enable cascading delete - the associated BirthYears will be deleted from the database when a Team is deleted.

**Edit 2**

(Again based on Ladislav's comment) If you don't want to replicate the years in the BirthYears table you could also setup a Many-To-Many relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasMany(t => t.BirthYears)
            .WithMany();
```

This will add a join table (`TeamBirthYears`) between `Team` and `BirthYear` into the database. From the viewpoint of storage space or performance you wouldn't probably win anything (since the `BirthYear` class is very small and a record in the `BirthYear` table has the same size as a record in the join table). But it might be a better approach if you have in mind to extend the `BirthYear` class by additional properties sooner or later. Otherwise I would personally keep it simple with the One-To-Many relationship. But the choice is yours.

Comment: This will throw exception. `BirthYear` must have another property which will be used as PK. Also once you expose `BirthYear` as separate entity relation will most probably become many-to-many or birth years will be repeated.

Comment: @Ladislav: True, this was a too sloppy answer, thanks for the hint! I've corrected it now. But when did you mean will a many-to-many relation occur? I had made now a small test and it seems to be a one-to-many relationship - optional without the Fluent code above and required with this code.

Comment: It is one-to-many but if I understand the scenario it should be probably many-to-many because otherwise you can have many records in BirthYear with the same value.

Comment: Now I see. On the other hand, what we would save in the BirthYear table we would need in the join table then. But I'm going to add this as another option into the answer.

Comment: Thanks..., Well I guess I have to create my on BirthYear class then to make it work.